# Passing a collection via link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to open a form via `remote:true` method. The form which i am opening has a `@projects` variable. How can i pass this `@projects` variable via `link_to` method.

```
<%= link_to "", project_path, remote:true, class="icon", id:"icon" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code

```
<%= link_to "", project_path(:projects => @projects), remote: true, class: "icon", id: "icon" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "", project_path(projects: @projects), remote: true, class: "icon", id: "icon" %>
```

Comment: `class="icon"` should not be used here, it sets the variable `class` equal to the string `"icon"` (and `class` is a reserved word in Ruby). Use `class: 'icon'` instead

Comment: yes that is correct, i forgot to change that.. Thnaks MrYoshiji